# How to connect the bridge node of painlessmesh to AWS IoT Core to publish message via MQTT?

Tags: mqtt, esp8266, aws-iot, mesh-networks, bridge

**Background:**

I am trying to work with two ESP8266 nodes using the painless mesh. Until now the painless mesh worked fine. At next level i made one of the node as bridge or root node. My intention here now is that the root node should fetch the data from AWS IoT i.e., get subscribed to a topic and get the data and relay the same data to the other child node. Here the protocol i needed to use for communication between the ESP8266 and AWS is MQTT.

As part of connecting to AWS IoT core, i had to use the certificates created for a particular thing in AWS IoT to load it into my root node.

**Problem:**

Here i am facing an issue saying that the AWS certificates i used to form communication between root node and AWS is "Either expired or not valid". After some research, i found that for SSL certificates to be considered as valid, proper current time stamp has to be considered in the root node. By default the node would have a initial value of the time stamp like year for ex. 1970. To solve this error i used the NTP client and part of the code to force update the time stamp to current time. Still i am facing an issue where the root node is unable to connect to the AWS through MQTT and also the normal painless mesh activity is also affected by this.

I am a beginner to all this concepts regarding painless mesh. Please help me regarding this.
Any suggestion or solution would be very helpful for me.

Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not understanding what your question is about. I've never heard of painless mesh, but I would like to help. I am very familiar with MQTT and internet of things projects. Can you review IoT concepts and terminology? And then speak in those terms? The more clear you are, the easier it is for folks to help. Also, please explain what AWS is and NTP client.

Comment: @jsotola Be sure to edit if you spot any typos; you can leave a message in the edit description to help the author too.